# Stories shared on my website doesn't appear in the facebook news feed anymore

Tags: facebook, share, feed

Our sharing buttons have been working just fine and the news were appearing in the news feed every time they were shared.
I have no idea what happened but as from yesterday, the buttons are working, the story appears on the user Time Line but it just won't appear in the news feed and we've tried this with 5 different accounts.

The app is totally OK, no warnings or errors.

If someone has this problem as well and can suggest something, I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here is what happened: Seems like FB has blocked our site for some reason (maybe an auto-check together with their strange algorithms or something).
I've contacted them and after 12 hours... whoala - it started to show on the news feed again.

So if someone has this problem and he is 100% certain that his technical setup has no errors, just go ahead and contact Facebook, they'll help you.